# AC rms value of pulse train vs RMS value

Tags: ac, pulse, rms

I have a pulse train with Duty Cycle = 1/4, that oscillates from 0V to 3V. 
I found the RMS value to be

$$ RMS = V \sqrt{D} = 3 \times 1/2 = 1.5 V $$

The DC offset, since it's oscillating from 0V to 3V, is 1.5 V.

What is the AC RMS value? When I use the formula: \$RMS^2 = DC^2+AC_{rms}^2\$ and substitute for RMS and DC, I get \$AC_{rms}= 0V\$

What am I missing?

Am I doing the DC offset wrong? Should the DC offset really be the average value, so its \$V \times D = 3 \times 1/4 = 3/4\$?

Then the \$AC_{RMS} = 1.5^2-(3/4)^2 = \sqrt{27/16}\$ ?

Comment: DC offset it is not a product of oscillation. It is a DC voltage above zero axis, and it is included to the original signal (in case of DC coupling) or not (in case of AC coupling) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If \$\lambda \in [0,1]\$ is the duty cycle, then the
RMS voltage is \$\sqrt{\lambda} V_\max \$, the DC voltage is \$\lambda V_\max\$ and the
RMS value about the average is \$\sqrt{\lambda(1-\lambda)} V_\max \$.

You have
\$ ( \sqrt{\lambda} V_\max ) ^2 = (\lambda V_\max) ^2 + ( \sqrt{\lambda(1-\lambda)} V_\max )^2\$,
that is, the total RMS squared is the sum of the DC squared and the square of the RMS value about the DC value. The latter works because the DC component and the AC (about the DC value) component are 'independent'.

In the above, \$\lambda = {1 \over 4} \$, \$V_\max=3\$ so we have
an RMS voltage of \${3 \over 2} \$ Volts,
a DV voltage of \${3 \over 4} \$ Volts and
an RMS value about the average of \${3\sqrt{3} \over 4} \$ Volts.